# Statsmodel ADF function returning "TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python

Sorry, I'm a little new with functions, and while I googled the problem and think that it's an indexing issue, I'm not quite sure how to fix it. I have a hunch it may be in this line --

`dftest[0:4]`

It runs fine, but when I try and call the function I get the

```
/tmp/ipykernel_42/1549980085.py in <module>
----> 1 adf_test(df_total['Total Deaths'])

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

The code

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

def adf_test(dataset):
    print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
    dftest = adfuller(dataset, autolag="AIC")
    dfoutput = pd.Series(
        dftest[0:4],
        index=[
            "Test Statistic",
            "p-value",
            "#Lags Used",
            "Number of Observations Used",
        ],
    )
    for key, value in df_total[4].items():
        dfoutput["Critical Value (%s)" % key] = value
    print(dfoutput)
adf_test(df_total['Total Deaths])
```

df_total

```
Entity  Code    Year    Total Deaths
0   Afghanistan AFG 1990    299.477309
1   Afghanistan AFG 1991    291.277967
2   Afghanistan AFG 1992    278.963056
3   Afghanistan AFG 1993    278.790815
4   Afghanistan AFG 1994    287.162923
5   Afghanistan AFG 1995    288.014224
6   Afghanistan AFG 1996    286.642589
7   Afghanistan AFG 1997    286.447455
8   Afghanistan AFG 1998    286.265202
9   Afghanistan AFG 1999    286.636018
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the df_total[4] as shown below

```
for key, value in df_total[4].items():
        dfoutput["Critical Value (%s)" % key] = value
    print(dfoutput)
```

to df_total['Total Deaths']

```
   for key, value in df_total["Total Deaths"].items():
        dfoutput["Critical Value (%s)" % key] = value
    print(dfoutput)
```

And get the output

```
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:
Test Statistic                -1.309915e+01
p-value                        1.724308e-24
#Lags Used                     7.000000e+00
Number of Observations Used    6.460000e+03
Critical Value (0)             2.994773e+02
                                   ...     
Critical Value (6463)          1.438501e+02
Critical Value (6464)          1.382005e+02
Critical Value (6465)          1.327526e+02
Critical Value (6466)          1.286921e+02
Critical Value (6467)          1.250288e+02
Length: 6472, dtype: float64
```

However, I feel like this isn't the optimal way, because I'm using the column name now. And aren't exactly sure if this correct results.

Any clarification would be great thanks!